# LinkedInOAuthServiceException java.io.FileNotFoundException: https://api.linkedin.com/uas/oauth/requestToken

Tags: android, oauth, linkedin-api

I have done the integration of linked-in on the android studio but I have a facing difficult error.  If anyone knows please let me know. I'm stuck here.

Exact error line is getAuthorizationUrl(); method has throw as OauthLinkedin----->com.google.code.linkedinapi.client.oauth.LinkedInOAuthServiceException: oauth.signpost.exception.OAuthCommunicationException: Communication with the service provider failed: https://api.linkedin.com/uas/oauth/requestToken

```html
  if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT > 9) {
            StrictMode.ThreadPolicy policy = new StrictMode.ThreadPolicy.Builder().permitAll().build();
            StrictMode.setThreadPolicy(policy);
        }
  

    
 @OnClick(R.id.createAccForLikedin)
    public void createAccForLikedinClick(Button button) {
        progress.setMessage("Please Wait while we Redirect...");
        progress.setCanceledOnTouchOutside(false);
        progress.show();
        getLinkedinLogin();
    }


public void getLinkedinLogin() {
        oAuthService = LinkedInOAuthServiceFactory.getInstance()
                .createLinkedInOAuthService(Constants.CONSUMER_KEY,
                        Constants.CONSUMER_SECRET);
        System.out.println("oAuthService : " + oAuthService);

        factory = LinkedInApiClientFactory.newInstance(
                Constants.CONSUMER_KEY, Constants.CONSUMER_SECRET);

        liToken = oAuthService
                .getOAuthRequestToken(Constants.OAUTH_CALLBACK_URL);

        Intent i = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse(liToken
                .getAuthorizationUrl()));
        startActivity(i);
    }
  

 @Override
    protected void onNewIntent(Intent intent) {
        super.onNewIntent(intent);

        try {
             linkedInImport(intent);
        } catch (NullPointerException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```